# &gt; being displayed as &gt; in browser and not >

Tags: html, asp-classic

I am trying to convert a string that contains XML into something that can be displayed in a browser. To do so I am passing the string to the following function:

```
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim regEx
    Dim matches
    Dim match
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(34), "&quot;")
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(60), "&lt;")
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(62), "&gt;")
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(38), "&amp;")
    sText = Replace(sText, Chr(32), "&nbsp;")


    Set regEx= New RegExp

    With regEx
     .Pattern = "&#(\d+);" 'Match html unicode escapes
     .Global = True
    End With

    Set matches = regEx.Execute(sText)

    'Iterate over matches
    For Each match in matches
        'For each unicode match, replace the whole match, with the ChrW of the digits.

        sText = Replace(sText, match.Value, ChrW(match.SubMatches(0)))
    Next

    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
```

However when I call, as follows:

```
response.write HTMLDecode(strResponse)
```

the conversion happens but this is what I see in the browser:

```
 &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot;? &gt;
```

rather than

```
<xml version="1.0"? >
```

Happens in IE, FF & Chrome so I guess it must be my code - any ideas?

Comment: I don't know ASP, but is there really a need to reinvent HTML escaping by hand?

Comment: Thanks for the unhelpful comment. Classic asp doesn't have anything to do what I want so that is why I am forced to "reinvent HTML escaping".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Server.HTMLEncode(strResponse)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using [HttpUtility.HtmlDecode Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332854%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I think that is for .NET and this is classic asp??